# C++ very long integer digit counter

Tags: c++, integer, long-integer

I have an assignment to create a program in C++ which would count digits of extremely long integers.

I am given two random numbers a and b (1 <= a, b <= 10^16). I need to find how many digits does a number a^b (a to the power b) has. (I don't need to know the number itself, only how many digits it has)

I had few ideas on how to solve this problem, one way I thought about it is creating a separate structure which would hold these very long integers and would be able to do multiplication on them, but it would take extremely long to do multiplication that many times, and the time limit for the program is 1s. Maybe there is some kind of function or something like that in C++ which could help me out?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: By `^` you mean xor or power? I assume this is power, because 10^16 xor 10^16 is not a big number

Comment: I think he meant power, not xor

Comment: I meant a to the power b.

Comment: I think something like `b * log10(a)` should work

Comment: For the next post, please show your own effort.

Comment: For _this_ post, please show your own effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of digits of a number `N` in base `B` is floor(log<sub>B</sub>N) + 1. So you need to calculate floor(log<sub>10</sub>(a<sup>b</sup>)) + 1 which is equal to floor(b*log<sub>10</sub>a) + 1

floor rounds the number down to the nearest integer. Both floor and log10 functions are available in `<cmath>` library

Comment: I think you should add 1 and round to floor instead, because `10 * log10(10) = 10`, but 10^10 has 11 digits

Answer (score 1):

using logarithm, this can be solved with "small" numbers:
log (a^b) = log (a) * b

the number you are looking for is going to be

```
auto exp = math.log10(a) * b;
```

you will need to round thix result to the lower integer higher than this value

Comment: I think that it should be clarified that you should always round up to the nearest integer higher than `exp` - no matter if it contains decimals or not. Otherwise it will give wrong answer for 10^10

Answer (score 0):

you will took to numbers from user and you will do (int temp) to used it in code and you will call a pow function from (cmath) library and if you want to print the power of two numbers calling this function and you will do a for loop from (1) to (power number) and in this loop you will equal temp and counter and out of loop you will print this temp
 and this is the code .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void power_digit();

int main()
{
    power_digit();   
}
void power_digit()
{
    int x , y ,temp ;
    string result;
    cout << "\nEnter number one :";
    cin >> x ;
    cout << "\nEnter number two :";
    cin >> y ;
    cout << "The power of x and y is : "<< pow(x,y);
      for (int i = 1 ; i < y ; i++)
    {
        temp =  i ;
    }
    cout << "\nThe digit of result is :" << temp;
}
```